# Issue with bundling Tailwind CSS in Vue 3 widget library using Vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, tailwind-css, vite

I'm developing a widget library using Vue 3, Vite, and Tailwind CSS, but I'm facing an error during the bundling process. It appears that the issue is specifically related to the inclusion of Tailwind CSS styles in the final bundled files. Although the styles are correctly implemented and displayed in Storybook, they are not being applied in the bundled files.

I've followed the documentation and tried multiple approaches, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Here's the vite configuration files:

```
import path from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import postcssConfig from './postcss.config.js';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), dts({
    insertTypesEntry: true,
  })], 
  css:{
    postcss: postcssConfig
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'repx_widget',
      formats: ['es'], // adding 'umd' requires globals set to every external module
      fileName: (format: any) => `repx_widget.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // external modules won't be bundled into your library
      external: ['vue', /primevue\/.+/], // not every external has a global
      output: {
        // disable warning on src/index.ts using both default and named export
        exports: 'named',
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps (not useful if 'umd' is not in lib.formats)
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
          tailwindcss: 'tailwindcss',
        },
      },
    },
    emptyOutDir: false, // to retain the types folder generated by tsc
  },
});
```

I've also created a GitHub repository with the entire codebase for reference:(https://github.com/poojithaaprakash/vue-widget/tree/master)

Any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: "I'm encountering an error". Please include all details; how can others help you to debug ? :)